# Is this regression problem solvable?

Tags: regression, linear-model, multivariate-analysis, matrix, compression

I have a random vector $\pmb{x}=(X_1,...,X_p)^T\in \mathbb{R}^p$, a symmetric matrix
$$\Theta = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & \theta_{12} & \theta_{13} & \cdots & \theta_{1p}\\
\theta_{12} & 0 & \theta_{23} & \cdots & \theta_{2p}\\
\theta_{13} & \theta_{23} & 0 & \cdots & \theta_{3p}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\theta_{1p} & \theta_{2p} & \theta_{3p} & \cdots & 0
\end{matrix} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p},$$
and a random error vector $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_p)^T\in \mathbb{R}^p$. In my setting, I have the following regression models
$$ \begin{matrix} X_1 = & & X_2 \theta_{12}+ & X_3 \theta_{13}+ & \cdots+ & X_{p-1}\theta_{1,p-1} + & X_p\theta_{1p} + & \epsilon_1 \\
X_2 = &  X_1 \theta_{12}+ &  & X_3 \theta_{23}+ & \cdots+ & X_{p-1}\theta_{2,p-1} + & X_p\theta_{2p} + & \epsilon_2 \\
X_3 = &  X_1 \theta_{13}+ & X_2 \theta_{23}+ &  & \cdots+ & X_{p-1}\theta_{3,p-1} + & X_p\theta_{3p} + & \epsilon_3 \\
\vdots \\
X_p = &  X_1 \theta_{1p}+ & X_2 \theta_{2p}+ & X_p\theta_{3p} + & \cdots+ & X_{p-1}\theta_{p-1,p-1} + &  & \epsilon_p \\
\end{matrix}$$
I can summarize them into matrix form
$$ \left(\begin{matrix}X_1\\X_2\\ \vdots\\X_p \end{matrix}\right) = \Theta\left(\begin{matrix}X_1\\X_2\\ \vdots\\X_p \end{matrix}\right) + \left(\begin{matrix}\epsilon_1\\\epsilon_2\\ \vdots\\\epsilon_p \end{matrix}\right)$$
and it further equals to
$$ \left(\begin{matrix}-1 & \theta_{12} & \theta_{13} & \cdots & \theta_{1p}\\
\theta_{12} & -1 & \theta_{23} & \cdots & \theta_{2p}\\
\theta_{13} & \theta_{23} & -1 & \cdots & \theta_{3p}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\theta_{1p} & \theta_{2p} & \theta_{3p} & \cdots & -1
\end{matrix} \right)\left(\begin{matrix}X_1\\X_2\\ \vdots\\X_p \end{matrix}\right) = -\left(\begin{matrix}\epsilon_1\\\epsilon_2\\ \vdots\\\epsilon_p \end{matrix}\right).$$
My questions is: How to estimate $\Theta$ given data $\{\pmb{x}_i\}_{i=1}^n $ i.i.d from $\pmb{x}$ with $p<n$?

I tried to read about trace regression introduced in High-Dimensional Statistics: A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint by Martin J. Wainwright, but I think my setting is different since the response vector and the predictor vector are the same. I guess this is related to matrix completion / compressed sensing, but I am not familiar with this literature and do not know where to start. Does anyone have suggestions?

My setting needs $p>n$, and I guess I can simply add some penalty term. Any literature I can have a look at?

Comment: crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466850/is-this-regression-problem-solvable

Comment: Please if you crosspost, say so. It is ok to post after waiting some time and not getting an answer, but at least provide a link.

Comment: What properties would make a good estimator? Are you perhaps trying to minimize a certain loss function?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser Gotcha. Thank you for letting me know about this.

Comment: @Sycorax I am interested in getting a consistent estimation of Θ in terms of the Frobenius norm.